# Timeout error: vb standalone console application

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

i am working with a standalone console application that is throuwing a timeout error for a query. I verified the amount of time the query takes to execute and it takes exactly 12 seconds to finish in teh query analyser. But along witht application it is taking more than 1min. Since it is a standalone applicationthe issue of static and dynamic ip's mixing do not come into picture. Need to know if the system performence can affect the time out constraint

Comment: Could you provide us some code?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your application? Visual Studio has a CPU profiler included. It will tell you exactly how much % time was spent working on the query, as well as on processing the rest of your code.

Comment: Sorry Max cant provide the code. 
Neolisk, is there any way to complete a profiling operation without the team edition ?